# Access an NTFS volume in Linux LVM from Windows

Tags: linux, windows, lvm, partitioning

my system dual boots Windows 7 and Debian Linux. My linux partition uses LVM with a root swap setup. My swap size is 18 GB and the root size is 2 TB. I resized my root partition to 750GB to give me 1.25 TB of free space for additional data in Windows. I then formatted this free space to NTFS.

When I boot into Windows I can see the drive the LVM resides on but I do not see the NTFS portion. Does anyone know how I would go about accessing the NTFS volume in Windows?

Thanks much,

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/ might be your best bet. I don't know of any other tool which can access LVM partitions from Windows. Its supposed to have LVM2 support--you might need to make the volume ext2/3/4 though.

Comment: Thanks I tried ext2read and its support of LVM appears to be very limited. I don't see my root or swap volumes, just grub.

Comment: I am pretty sure this isn't going to be possible in any way that you could rely on.  Your best bet is to delete the volume, reduce your volume group size, and create a new partition with the empty space.

Comment: You mean create a new partition outside the LVM? I thought about that but I am not sure how to move the free space outside of the LVM.